# How to fill bullet lists in comments

Tags: emacs, elisp

I’m often putting bullet lists in “//“-style comments, e.g.:

```
// * Here’s a very long line containing a bullet and I want
//   it to fill like this.  Note the leading space here
//
// * Here’s the next bullet in that same bullet list.
```

However, I am unable to get `M-q` to fill the list that way by any obvious customization of newcomment.el variables.  It always comes out like this:

```
// * Here’s a very long line containing a bullet and I want
// it to fill like this.
```

It doesn’t seem to be possible to make this work easily using regexps (with `comment-use-syntax` set to `nil`).  Do I need to use syntax tables?

Comment: I want the wrapped line to be indented to match the beginning of the text following the bullet.

Answer (score 1):

Paragraphs inside comments still work, you just need to separate them by empty commented line:

```
// * Here’s a very long line containing a bullet and I want
// it to fill like this.
//
// * Here’s the next bullet in that same bullet list.
```

Note that the 2nd and following lines aren't indented.

Comment: I think the OP wants the extra space in front of the 2nd line of the first bullet point, i.e. in front of "it to fill like this"

Comment: @MarkFisher: The question has changed since I answered it.

Comment: ah, that explains that then.